# RSA Archer subscription notification

Tags: archer

How to generate subscription notification which will trigger every six months from the first published date. For ex: record is created on 1/1/2018. Notification should be sent on 1/6/2018. Again, for the same record notification sent on 1/12/2018.

Comment: Please show what you have managed to come up with so that it can be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this approximately by setting the Frequency to Reminder. In the criteria, you would select First Published Equals 180 days Before Date. **Date** in this case means the current date - so you would be comparing First Published = 180 Days before now. Hope this helps!

Comment: Reminder would only be sent out once. Pallavi wants it to be triggered every 180 days.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of this as of now:
Create a calculated values-list field with the following calculation and use it as a criteria, in a subscription notification.

```
IF(
     MOD(DATEDIF(TODAY(), [First Published], DAY),180) = 0,
     VALUEOF([This Field],"Yes"), VALUEOF([This Field],"No")
)
```

Set this notification on Daily frequency. This way, it'll be triggered for all the records satisfying the 180 days criteria on each given day.

Note: Do not use DDE notification for this.